# Trying to match characters between delimiter

Tags: regex

The delimiter is `-`(with space before and after the dash)
and the text is : `Information and Telecommunication - Salaries and Wages - Non-Management`. The texts I am trying to match are `Information and Telecommunication`, `Salaries and Wages`, and `Non-Management`

The closest regex I have gotten to is `(\s-\s)?[\w\s]+(\s-\s)?`, but unfortunately the match yields `Non` and `Management` as separate matches.

*Another Case to try*: `Information and Telecommunication - Salaries and Wages - Non-Management - 1--2`

Comment: Isn't it better to split the string by ` - ` ?

Comment: @JohnyL, Split functions might be easy for a single character delimiter but not for a pattern such as ` - ` (with spaces before and after the dash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either a space with optional hyphen  `-` or  a hyphen with optional space `-`   but not  `-`

```
\w+(?:(?: -*|-+ ?)\w+)*
```

The pattern matches

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?: -*|-+ ?)` either match   and 0+ `-` OR match 1+ times `-` and optional
  - `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8zLBY0/1)

Comment: Although I like the simplicity of the first regex expression you have pasted. When testing with the following example data: ```Information and Telecommunication - Salaries and Wages - Non-Management - 1--2```, yielded 1 and 2 as separate matches.

Comment: @Vivek You could for example repeat the - like  `\w+(?:(?: -*|-+ ?)\w+)*`  see https://regex101.com/r/8zLBY0/1

Comment: the solution you just provided works. If you want to edit your answer to paste this new answer, go for it. Going through the inner most non-capturing group: `(?: -*|-+ ?)` I made the following observation that spaces cannot be depicted in the alternation with ` \s` shorthand.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll need in fact is a regex that matches word characters, or spaces or hyphens that are just before either `-` or the end of the line

The following regex should do

```
(\w(?:[\w\s]|\w-\w)*)(?=(?:\s-\s)|$)
```

Explanation

```
(             # matching group start
  \w          # match any word character once
    (?:       # start of a non-matching group
      [\w\s]  # match any word character or space character
      |       # OR
      \w-\w   # match any hyphen that's in between two word characters
    )*        # find this non-matching group zero or multiple times
)             # matching group end
(?=           # lookahead start
  (?:\s-\s)   # non-matching group for space hyphen space
  |           # OR
  $           # end of string
)             # lookahead end
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VYu5jK/1/)

Comment: When testing with the following example data: ```Information and Telecommunication - Salaries and Wages - Non-Management - 1--2```, yielded 1 and 2 as separate matches.